# How to configure combined buildType and flavor variant

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have two build types `debug` and `release` and two flavors `red` and `blue` and my goal is to do something only for `redDebug` variant.

I want to configure a combination of buildType and flavor as a BaseExtension extension:

```
fun BaseExtension.configureVariants(
    configureRedDebug: BuildType.() -> Unit = {},
    configureBlueDebug: BuildType.() -> Unit = {},
    configureRedRelease: BuildType.() -> Unit = {},
    configureBlueRelease: BuildType.() -> Unit = {},
)
```

Is it possible to implement such a combination? If yes, how to achieve it?